# How to get 'photo'_url(...) to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

`photo_url(Photo.first, :host => 'foobar')` returns `http://foobar/photos/2vig0` .

How do I do the same thing with something like `'photo'_url(Photo.first, :host => 'foobar')`

Do I need to do something like: `'photo'.constantize._url(Photo.first, :host => 'foobar')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `send` to invoke a method, once you've concatinated the two parts of the string together.

assuming `@fn` contains the string `"photo"`:

```
send("#{@fn}_url", Photo.first, :host => 'foobar')
```

Or, possibly clearer:

```
send("photo" + "_url", Photo.first, :host => 'foobar')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about url_for?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for